# Run a command-line file that has output, but bypass that and allow me to continue running commands

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm trying to run some php files that have output and can take up to an hour to run, but I don't need to see the output as its writing to a log file (or I can push output to a log file) and I want to be able to run commands while its running (I don't care to be notified in any way that it's done; I can just go check the log file). How would I do this?

Comment: You don't tell us what operating system you're running. Such information would be important...

Comment: Sorry, it's Linux. They all behave the same way that I've ever seen on any of them in regards to this issue though. I type a command, it sits there outputting while I wait. I simply want to have it bring me back to the command line while it runs, whether it has output or not. Like, I want to funnel the output to /dev/null or something. I'm running CentOS 6.3 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this

```
command
```

ctrl-Z to interrupt

```
jobs
```

(list all jobs in your current shell, assuming there is only one)

```
bg
```

will take the top job in your queue and put it in the background

Or, just start it in the background from the beginning

```
command &
```

Any STDERR or STDOUT will show up on the screen so you will want to redirect those to a file

Comment: OK, I think this brings me closer. I don't know why you're the only one to understand my question or why this isn't a more asked-about issue. The admins closed this as not a real question yet you got it! Thanks.

Comment: np, if you need more help on this message me I guess if this is closed.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use a different ssh session or use a terminal multiplexer like [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).